# Is there an Erwin Macro to pull out the table comment/definition?

Tags: database, datamodel

I created a script template to generate the extendend properties to basically to include the data dictionary in the database, however, i couldn't find any macro to read-out the table comment from the model.  Is there any hack for this?

Comment: If you have found out by now, I'd be interested in the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The is DBMS specific in ERwin.

Depending on the dbms - SQL server or oracle will have a FET template.
for sql server.
if you edit the sql server template for creating schema. which in sql server is what generate comments or udp extended properties.  here is what is shown.

```
/* Generate comments and UDP's as Extended Properties. */
[
    /* Set the variables required by the "Clause: Specify Extended Properties". */
    Set( "var_RemoveVariables", "true" ) 
    Set( "var_Operation", "sp_addextendedproperty" ) 
    Set( "var_Comment", "Definition" )
    Set( "var_Level0Type", "SCHEMA" ) 
    Set( "var_Level0Name", Property( "Name" ) )

    /* Generate Schema comments and UDPs */
    Execute( "Clause: Specify Extended Properties" )
]

[ 
    FE::Bucket( "150" ) 
    ForEachOwnee( "Permission" )
    {
        Execute( "Create Permission" )
    }
]
```

]